# This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 102

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using VS Code and Anaconda3.
Currently trying to install ChromeDriver_Binary but, when I try to execute code, I get this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 102
> Current browser version is 100.0.4896.127 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Comment: Try updating your Chrome from 100 to 102 .

Comment: I tried to update from chrome, and I got the new version of Versión 101.0.4951.54 (Build oficial) (64 bits). Still not 102, also I downloaded the chromeDriver 101 from chromeAPI, tho I can't figure how to install Exe to python...

Answer (score 21):

One option is to use [chromedriver-autoinstaller](https://github.com/yeongbin-jo/python-chromedriver-autoinstaller) to do it all at once:

```
import chromedriver_autoinstaller as chromedriver
chromedriver.install()
```

Alternatively use [chromedriver-binary-auto](https://github.com/danielkaiser/python-chromedriver-binary) to find the required version and install the driver:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall chromedriver-binary-auto
import chromedriver_binary
```

No restarting is required.

Comment: Good solution! Simple and works.

Comment: Very nice work! Worked where everything else failed!

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these approaches worked for [my issue with getting the latest version of chromedriver automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74279326/undetected-chromedriver-requires-newer-chromedriver-version-than-automatically).

Comment: It works perfectly (Python 3.9, Win11). 
For what it's worth, i used this solution with a proxy and this one should be activated before the ```chromedriver.install()``` line and, then, desactivated before ```webdriver.Chrome()``` line

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it, by updating chrome to version 101, downloading chromedriver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and rebooting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I'm running MacOS Monterrey. My Chrome version is Version 104.0.5112.79.
I was getting the same error as you; This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 102

What I did was:

1. Download the version of chromedriver that matched the version of Chrome, in this case 104
   https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
2. Opened the location of chromedriver, it's usually  under this path: /usr/local/bin

- Open Finder.
- Press Command-Shift-G to open the dialogue box
- Input the following search: /usr/local/bin

3. Replaced the previous chromedriver from that location with the new one I just downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the updated code to install the latest version of Google Chrome and the latest version of ChromeDriver in Ubuntu, and move the ChromeDriver executable to /usr/local/bin/chromedriver:

```
# Install the latest version of Google Chrome
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f

# Install the latest version of ChromeDriver
CHROME_VERSION=$(google-chrome-stable --version | grep -oE '[0-9]{2}')
LATEST_CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=$(wget -q -O - https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_$CHROME_VERSION)
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$LATEST_CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/

# Clean up downloaded files
rm chromedriver_linux64.zip google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Or,
Here is the code in one command (Easy to Copy):

```
LATEST_CHROME=$(curl -s https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages | grep -E "^Version:" | awk '{ print $2 }' | head -n1 | cut -d'-' -f1) && LATEST_CHROMEDRIVER=$(curl -sS https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE) && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable && wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$LATEST_CHROMEDRIVER/chromedriver_linux64.zip && unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && sudo mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/ && sudo apt-get install -y fonts-liberation
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your current chrome version first, and then download the chrome driver following this version: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

The point here is that we have to make sure both of chrome version are the same

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

chrome browser and the chromedriver.exe(Path provided by the project) versions should match to the same version.

Answer (score 0):

please follow the below steps:

1-  Delete the current chrome driver from visual studio.

2-  Download the latest release of the chrome driver.

3-  Add the new chrome drive to the project ( follow below steps)
3.a- Copy the chrome driver to the application path on your pc for
example:C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\APPAutomation\APPAutomation
3.b- Select the project in Visual Studio and press on Add – existing item
3.c- Select the chromedriver exe file in Visual Studio.
3.d- Go to the properties of the chrome driver and change the “Copy to Output Directory” to “Copy if newer”

4-  End the chrome driver task from task manager (back ground process)

5-  Delete the Bin file from the project path

6-  Build the project in Visual Studio .

Answer (score 0):

This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 106
Current browser version is 108.0.4896.127 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

I was getting exact same error

steps I followed:

1. delete the old chromedriver.exe file.
2. download the chromedriver.exe file which is compatible with my
   chrome version which is 108. so I downloaded 108 and it worked.

[downloadable link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=108.0.5359.71/)

[image: attached is the link and pic of from where you can download.]

Answer (score -1):

Simply update the dependency for selenium specified in your dependency management tool.

Comment: Please post detailed answer, you post this as a comment.

Comment: Chrome usually gets updated automatically. So suppose you installed v100 of chrome on your system, whenever chrome releases v101 it gets updated on your system and your current version of chrome becomes v101. Now selenium version you were using was supporting v100, so it won't support v101 and thus you get an error. Update your selenium version to the latest one, it will solve above issue.

Comment: I am using Java with Maven. So I simply updated maven dependency of selenium for the version and solved the issue.