# cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:50385 .This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 116.0.5845.141

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, web-testing, undetected-chromedriver

**I am trying to use Python undetected-chromedriver==3.0.6 for web automation and web scraper.**

*I want to search Google using python selenium. I want to enter Google using Python Selenium but my coding shows the below error.*

This is the simple code I am trying to use

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import freeze_support

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()

    url = "https://www.google.com/"

    chrome_driver = uc.Chrome()
    chrome_driver.get(url)
    sleep(5)
    scraped_page = chrome_driver.page_source
    chrome_driver.quit()
    print(scraped_page)
```

**However, I get the error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anik Saha\Desktop\VFSBot\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    chrome_driver = uc.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\Anik Saha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\v2.py", line 309, in __init__
    super(Chrome, self).__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Anik Saha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 84, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Anik Saha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Anik Saha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Anik Saha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\v2.py", line 600, in start_session
    super(Chrome, self).start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Anik Saha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Anik Saha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Anik Saha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:50655
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.141
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x010CA813+48355]
        (No symbol) [0x0105C4B1]
        (No symbol) [0x00F65358]
        (No symbol) [0x00F861AC]
        (No symbol) [0x00F806B4]
        (No symbol) [0x00F80491]
        (No symbol) [0x00FB0C55]
        (No symbol) [0x00FB093C]
        (No symbol) [0x00FAA536]
        (No symbol) [0x00F882DC]
        (No symbol) [0x00F893DD]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0132AABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0136A78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0136456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x011551E0+616112]
        (No symbol) [0x01065F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x01062328]
        (No symbol) [0x0106240B]
        (No symbol) [0x01054FF7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x754500C9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x775E7B1E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x775E7AEE+238]
```

**My current Chrome version:**

[image]

**Current Python Version:**
Python 3.10.5

Comment: Try updating your chrome webdriver. download the last version from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72123590/14112076

Answer (score 1):

@ylj you provided wrong url that doesn't contain latest drivers
Well, this problem can be solved in 2 ways:

1. Upload latest [driver](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable)
2. Use selenium version 4.11.0 and above with DriverManager, that provide proper links with latest drivers

[selenium driver implementation](https://github.com/DimaBerezovskyi/simple-python-selenium-framework/blob/main/src/utils/driver.py%5D) 
[selenium driver manager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/)